# How to force precision in region plots containing Erfc

Tags: plotting, numerics, precision-and-accuracy

I'm trying to use regionplot for functions that involve `Erfc`. A slightly contrived example follows, but it illustrates my difficulties. The command

```
ContourPlot[Erfc[x] == Erfc[y], {x, -12, 0}, {y, -12, 0}]
```

should give a diagonal line but doesn't:

[image]

I can force the correct result in Mathematica 11.2 by increasing `WorkingPrecision`:

```
ContourPlot[Erfc[x] == Erfc[y], {x, -12, 0}, {y, -12, 0}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

[image]

How can I similarly force higher `WorkingPrecision` using RegionPlot

```
RegionPlot[Erfc[x] > Erfc[y], {x, -12, 0}, {y, -12, 0}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Note that `WorkingPrecision -> 10` is not technically an "increase" in precision, but it does take you out of the domain of machine floats.*  Within the domain of machine reals, a value can get only so close to `2.` (`$MachineEpsilon` if the value is below `2`).  For all `x < -6` or so, the floating-point number closest to the value of `Erfc[x]` is `2.`.  So in the whole square in the bottom left of the first graph in the OP, both `Erfc[x]` and `Erfc[y]` are equal when evaluated at machine precision.

```
Table[Erfc[x] - 2., {x, -12., -5.}]
(*  {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1.53744*10^-12}  *)
```

*Note: The underlying representation of an arbitrary-precision number has extra "guard digits."  In the case where the precision is less than `$MachinePrecision` (~15.95), the equivalent of two floats (double-precision) seem to be used, so that the point-estimates of a calculation at precision `10` (or even `4`) are done with around 30 digits.

---

For `RegionPlot`, `WorkingPrecision` seems to have no effect.  To evaluate the functions at higher precision, use `SetPrecision` like this:

```
RegionPlot[
 With[{z = SetPrecision[x, 20]}, Erfc[z]] > With[{z = SetPrecision[y, 20]}, Erfc[z]],
 {x, -12, 0}, {y, -12, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is it the case then that RegionPlot works only with machine floating points, as opposed to ContourPlot? I suppose one alternative is to precalculate high-precision values in an array and find a way to plot the sign of these.

Comment: @Øistein Yes, that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 4):

Use the relation `Erfc[x] == 1 - Erf[x]`. The two argument form of `Erf` is specifically to tackle these precision issues:

```
ContourPlot[Erf[x, y] == 0, {x, -12, 0}, {y, -12, 0}]
```

> `Erf[z0, z1]` gives the generalized error function `Erf[z1] - Erf[z0]` [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Erf.html)

As for your second example:

```
Erfc[x] > Erfc[y] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> Erf[y] > Erf[x]
> ```

So `Erf[x,y] > 0` or

```
RegionPlot[Erf[x, y] > 0, {x, -12, 0}, {y, -12, 0}]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it was just a contrived example; I'm working with inequalities that cannot be put on a form in which I can use Erf[x,y]. My question is about the graphics: I struggle understanding why ContourPlot can be forced to handle the problem using WorkingPrecision while RegionPlot cannot. Sorry if that wasn't clear.